# Serialize relation both ways with Django rest_framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I wonder how to serialize the mutual relation between objects both ways with "djangorestframework". Currently, the relation only shows one way with this:

```
class MyPolys(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.TextField()
    poly = models.PolygonField()

class MyPages2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    body = models.TextField()
    mypolys = models.ManyToManyField(MyPolys)

# ...

class MyPolysSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = testmodels.MyPolys

class MyPages2Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = testmodels.MyPages2

# ...

class MyPolyViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = testmodels.MyPolys.objects.all()
    serializer_class = srlz.MyPolysSerializer

class MyPages2ViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = testmodels.MyPages2.objects.all()
    serializer_class = srlz.MyPages2Serializer
```

The many-to-many relation shows up just fine in the api for MyPages2 but nor for MyPolys. How do I make rest_framework aware that the relation goes both ways and needs to be serialized both ways?

The question also applies to one-to-many relations btw.

So far, from reading the documentation and googling, I can't figure out how do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
class MyPolysSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = testmodels.MyPolys
        fields =('id','name','text','poly')


class MyPages2Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    mypolys = MyPolysSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = testmodels.MyPages2
        fields =('id','name','body','mypolys')
```

Comment: Thanks. However, that happens automatically - that MyPages2 shows the a field 'mypolys' linking it to those objects. What I lack is that MyPolys show their relation to MyPages2. I tried `class MyPolysSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): \n mypages2 = MyPages2Serializer(many=True, read_only=True) \n class Meta: \n model = testmodels.MyPolys \n fields = ('name', 'text', 'id', 'mypages2')` - no errors, also 'mypages2' is not displayed.

Comment: MyPolys oject is unaware of MyPages2, so in your serializer you have field mypolis : []  if empty or mypolis:[['id':1,....],['id':2....]]    when you add. ViewSet rendering MyPolys will not display anything related to mypages2, as mypages2 uses mypolys and not vise versa. ManyToMany means the object can be used somewhere else besides, but not in the object itself.

Comment: When you do m = MyPages2.objects.get(id=...)  and then m.mypolys.add(mypolis)  or m.mypolis.add(p=MyPolis.obects.get(id=1)) it will increase the json array

Comment: mypages2 is not part of the model MyPolys, so it can not be serialized in the serializer of MyPolys.

Comment: Thanks. How do I make the MyPolys class aware of the mutual relation to MyPages2? According to the book I read about Django "Django Unleashed", a many-to-many relationship btw two classes is only to be declared on one of them (either one, doesn't matter), as Django takes care of making the other class aware of the relation. If that is not the case, then how to make it aware of it? Btw, same issue in admin panel, not just REST interface.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to add to  MyPolys  a field - mypage2_id = models.IntegerField()          and when creating it pl = MyPolys.objects.create(mypage2_id=mypage2.id)   - you can't use foreign key field here as it's declared first in the script.

Comment: It appears not to be necessary to alter the `MyPolys` class. Django has indeed automatically added a similar field called `mypages2_set` to the `MyPolys` class - see my answer. Now, the question remains, how do I make the admin panel reflect that relation as well ..?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! It appears that by adding a `mypolys = models.ManyToManyField(MyPolys)` to the `MyPages2` class, Django has indeed automatically added a similar field called `mypages2_set` to the `MyPolys` class, so the serializer looks like this:

```
class MyPolysSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = testmodels.MyPolys
        fields = ('name', 'text', 'id', 'url', 'mypages2_set')
```

I found out by inspecting an instance of the class in the shell using `./manage.py shell`:

```
pol = testmodels.MyPolys.objects.get(pk=1)
pol. # hit the tab key after '.'
```

Hitting the tab key after the '.' reveals additional fields and methods including `mypages2_set`.